# How To Create A GUI In the CLI

Tags: windows, user-interface, command-line-interface

I am looking for instructions regarding how to create a pseudo-GUI in the command line interface in Windows. An example of something I am looking for is http://www.hiew.ru/.

My preferred programming languages are C, C++, VB.NET, and C#.

Comment: This is technically off-topic, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic but I think its worth an answer anyway because other users might find this helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library that provides utilities to create GUIs like the one mentioned by you.

ncurses itself it is C/C++ but there are binding for other languages, e.g. [Curses#](http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/)

For example, the mail client [mutt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) ([Screenshot from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aMutt.png) ) has been realized with ncurses.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library in C# that does this: https://github.com/flagbug/FlagConsole

My screenshots are all just basic examples, but it should be possible to create a GUI like in your screenshot